# Torque PBS vs Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, pbs, python-multiprocessing, torque

I have a Python script which is running on a server with 512 CPUs and 4TB memory. The script uses Python's Multiprocessing module for parallel processing by forking 30 parallel child processes. I now need to write a PBS script to remotely call the script from another server. I can see there are two approaches:
1. Keep the script unchanged and use qsub to submit a job running the script. Then the script will use Multiprocessing module for parallelization.
2. Change the script to a serial processing and then use PBS to submit 30 jobs with different arguments for parallelization.

Could anyone give me some clue on the pros and cons of the different approaches? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing, the pros and cons of each approach aren't terribly important since either way you are running multiple separate jobs as opposed to a single 512 process MPI job.

Since Torque is a new part of your workflow you will need to figure out what queue to use and what limits are placed on that queue. Limits will usually be setup by the administrator and may be set to favors a small number of large jobs, first approach, or a large number of small jobs, second approach. Running

```
qmgr -c 'p s'
```

will show you some of this information but a talk with the admin will let you know how they intend to use the system and hopefully give you some insight on how to get your jobs run.

If you find that there are no limits set you may want to consider the large number of small jobs approach. Getting a 20 processor job through the queue will be easier than getting a 200 processor job to run on a shared system.